# Index ElasticSearch Results Using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following index :

```
POST /cars/transactions/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 10000, "color" : "red", "make" : "honda", "sold" : "2014-10-28" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 20000, "color" : "red", "make" : "honda", "sold" : "2014-11-05" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 30000, "color" : "green", "make" : "ford", "sold" : "2014-05-18" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 15000, "color" : "blue", "make" : "toyota", "sold" : "2014-07-02" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 12000, "color" : "green", "make" : "toyota", "sold" : "2014-08-19" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 20000, "color" : "red", "make" : "honda", "sold" : "2014-11-05" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 80000, "color" : "red", "make" : "bmw", "sold" : "2014-01-01" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "price" : 25000, "color" : "blue", "make" : "ford", "sold" : "2014-02-12" }
```

And I am performing the following search :

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : { 
        "popular_colors" : { 
            "terms" : { 
              "field" : "color"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response that I receive is the following :

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "popular_colors": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "red",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "blue",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "green",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My question is , how can I re-index that document into a different index?

I tried :

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "cars"
    query => '{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : { 
        "popular_colors" : { 
            "terms" : { 
              "field" : "color"
            }
        }
    }
}'
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
```

But it does not work because the **search_type** of the plugin is scan and **it does not support aggregation**.

I also tried :

```
input {
 file {
  path => "C:\ELK-STACK\logstash-2.3.4\bin\out.json"
  start_position => "beginning"
  codec => json_lines }
  }
```

Where the content of out.json is :

`{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":8,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7l","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 10000, "color" : "red", "make" : "honda", "sold" : "2014-10-28" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7m","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 20000, "color" : "red", "make" : "honda", "sold" : "2014-11-05" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7p","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 12000, "color" : "green", "make" : "toyota", "sold" : "2014-08-19" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7o","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 15000, "color" : "blue", "make" : "toyota", "sold" : "2014-07-02" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7n","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 30000, "color" : "green", "make" : "ford", "sold" : "2014-05-18" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7q","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 20000, "color" : "red", "make" : "honda", "sold" : "2014-11-05" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7r","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 80000, "color" : "red", "make" : "bmw", "sold" : "2014-01-01" }},{"_index":"cars","_type":"transactions","_id":"AVexGB7_99OIq3MORm7s","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "price" : 25000, "color" : "blue", "make" : "ford", "sold" : "2014-02-12" }}]}}`

But it did not produce any output after

> Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
>
> Pipeline main started

I assume that this is because the json file is not prepared for the json plugin and that I need to do some preparation (like using Java API) but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, the [`elasticsearch`](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch) input plugin doesn't support aggregations. It is possible to use the [`http_poller`](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http_poller) input plugin in order to send an aggregation query to Elasticsearch at regular intervals (or only once a day). Then using an `elasticsearch` output, you can send the resulting aggregations to ES again.

The configuration basically goes like this (note that the aggregation query needs to be URL-encoded and sent to ES using the [`source=...` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string)).

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test1 => 'http://localhost:9200/cars/transactions/_search?source=%7B%22size%22%3A0%2C%22aggs%22%3A%7B%22popular_colors%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22color%22%7D%7D%7D%7D'
   }
   # checking once per day
   interval => 86400
   codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my_aggs"
  }
}
```